# Tweeter API 2 - get recent tweets without providing keyword

Tags: twitter, twitterapi-python

How to download recent tweets regardless of keyword? I want any recent tweet from the Twitter API version 2. Is it possible? If it is, how to write a query?

For example, it will download tweets containing word cat:

```
https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query=cat
```

but what query to use to use instead of ?? to get tweets for any keyword:

```
https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query=??
```

In API1.1, it was possible to use `*` as a query, but it seems it is not working for API2. If I commit a query I get the following error: `The query query parameter can not be empty`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would return far too many results as it would be all Tweets from all users, all over the world! The "recent" endpoint will limit results to those from the last 7 days but it would still be millions.

You can query just the tweets from a particular account (e.g. Stackoverflow) with:

```
https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query=from:stackoverflow
```